# How to dynamically add an event listener to a NodeElement

Tags: javascript, html, nodelist

What I need to achieve here is to add a click events listener to a series of span elements with image thumbnails in it, so to make them selectable. These are dynamically created when a user input a file using the relative form.

What I managed so far is referencing the newly created childNodes of the output element that contain them.

Html:

```
<div id="imageBox"><output id="list"><!-- Newly created span elements here --></output></div>
```

The relative script with global scope:

```
var father = document.getElementById('list');
var children = father.childNodes;
```

Then I handled the clicks globally within a body element listener:

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', function( event ) {

if (children) {

for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {

  children[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
    if(this.style.boxShadow === '') this.style.boxShadow ='0 0 1em blue';
    else this.style.boxShadow = '';}, false);
    }
  }

}, false);
```

But as I was expecting, it works just double-clicking the new element.

I tried to add a callback to a function that wraps the above for cycle, inside the function that reads and load the selected file input, but it doesn't work.

```
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

// Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

  // Only process image files.
  if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
    continue;
  }

  var reader = new FileReader();

  // Closure to capture the file information.
  reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
    return function(e) {
      // Render thumbnail.
      var span = document.createElement('span');
      span.innerHTML = ['<img class="thumb" src="', e.target.result,'" title="', escape(theFile.name), '"/>'].join('');
      document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);

      console.log(children.length);

      clickable();
    };
  })(f);

  // Read in the image file as a data URL.
  reader.readAsDataURL(f);
}


}

function clickable(){
if (children) {

for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {

  children[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
    if(this.style.boxShadow === '') this.style.boxShadow ='0 0 1em blue';
    else this.style.boxShadow = '';}, false);
    }
  }
}
```

Any idea on how to handle this so to make it working just with one click?

Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/b130p9tb/2/

PROGRESS UPDATE:

Now it is working as it should, responding to single click properly, but when trying to select more than one item it works only on pair or uneven value of items, accordingly to the number of those. E.g. : with one item, it works fine, but with two only the second is selectable. With three instead only the first and the third are, and so on.

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/b130p9tb/3/

Comment: Please show the callback you tried to add, so we can see what you did wrong.

Comment: Can you share the existing code or a demo over jsfiddle. This will help us understand the actual problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're adding listeners to all elements each time you add a picture. So when you add the first picture you have one event listener. Then when you add a second picture, your first element has 2 event listeners. So it selects, then immediately de-selects. Etc.

A simpler approach would be to add the **listener** on your **list element** and modify style using the **event target**. Event if the listener is on the list element, the target will be the actual clicked image. So with only one listener, you have the expected behavior. Also, you can simplify the style toggling using a class. Like this:

```
document.getElementById('list').addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    e.target.classList.toggle('selected');
}, false);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ugvqy1r5/1/

Comment: I am pretty sure I used the add Event Listener to 'list' approach earlier on during my tests but for some reason that did now work for me. I am glad you explained me what was the problem there, and the use of the toggle property is a nice touch.